# Как отловить правильно сбои в опубликованном приложении?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

Приложение уже опубликованно
, но в айтюнс аналитике приложения в графе сбои показывают сбои в количестве  четверти от всех иимеющихся сессий. Советовали подключить фабрик через приложение на мак, типа оно само всё настроит, но у меня все зависает. Подключил флари, логи моих событий приходят. А логи ошибок не знаю как правильно встроить. Вставил код с логами ошибок такой как в руководстве, на активити кнопки, на экраны. Но приходит просто количество открытий экранов или нажите кнопок , не сами крэши... помогите, как отловить??? Спасибо

Наконец справился с fabric, подключил. По нажатию на одну кнопку выдает крэши. Помогите теперь разобраться с панелью, что и почему...?
[image: Скрин]

> Raw Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
>
> 0 GuyFit 0x10686db11 -[Crashlytics crash] + 4
>
> 1 GuyFit 0x106777beb ProgressViewController.closeButton2(UIButton) ->
>   ()  (ProgressViewController.swift:40)
>
> 2 GuyFit 0x106777d1a @objc
>   ProgressViewController.closeButton2(UIButton) -> ()
>   (ProgressViewController.swift)
>
> 3 UIKit 0x108ca6a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
>
> 4 UIKit 0x108e19e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>
> 5 UIKit 0x108e1a143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] +
>   327
>
> 6 UIKit 0x108e19263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
>
> 7 UIKit 0x108d1999f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
>
> 8 UIKit 0x108d1a6d4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
>
> 9 UIKit 0x108cc5dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
>
> 10 UIKit 0x108c9f553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
>
> 11 CoreFoundation 0x107f0b301 
>   CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 17
>
> 12 CoreFoundation 0x107f0122c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
>
> 13 CoreFoundation 0x107f006e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
>
> 14 CoreFoundation 0x107f000f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>
> 15 GraphicsServices 0x10cdc6ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161 16 UIKit
>   0x108ca4f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
>
> 17 GuyFit 0x10681b372 main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
>
> 18 libdyld.dylib 0x10acad92d start + 1

А вот код действия самой кнопки

```
@IBAction func closeButton2(sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
}
```

Comment: врубить фабрик и загрузить обновление в аппстор

Comment: ну вот у вас там написано, что крэшится оно в ProgressViewController.swift на 40й строчке. постите что у вас там за код (желательно весь метод)

Comment: `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()` метод crash вызывает краш